# Python Print all from json

Tags: python, json

I am able to use the following code to extract one of the artist of all the artists in the list.

```
print (data['topartists']['artist'][0]['name'])
```

Now i would like the print to return all the artists names.

I would assume using for:

```
for i in data:
    print (data['topartists']['artist'][i]['name'])
```

However this results in the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode`

What should i add to print all the artists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate artists, not the data itself.

```
for i in data['topartists']['artist']:
    print (i['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You already got a good answer, so I will just give a little bit of background information.

The problem here is that

```
for i in data: ...
```

gives you a loop, where `i` are the individual elements in `data` and not the indices like `i=range(0,len(data))` as you probably expected.

---

**Solution for your code:**

Solution with `i` being a counter that goes through the list (C++/Java-style):

```
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    print (data['topartists']['artist'][i]['name'])
```

Solution that is closer to normal Python notation (what lnxmen proposed):

```
for artist in data['topartists']['artist']:
    print (artist['name'])
```

In this more *pythonic* solution, the loop lets you do something with each single element in the list (`for artist in list_of_artists`), instead of giving you a counter like `i`.